# OpenvVMS passing array of char argument to C-function from pascal

Tags: c, string, pascal

I wrote the next Pascal code

```
PROGRAM demo1 (OUTPUT);
%include "sqlr$include:sqlrdef.pas"
VAR
    query : VARYING [50] OF CHAR;
BEGIN
    query:= "select * from countries";
    sqlr$test (query);
END.
```

"sqlrdef.pas" file consist

```
[EXTERNAL] FUNCTION sqlr$test (data : string) : INTEGER; EXTERNAL;
```

sqlr$test it is a C-function

```
unsigned long SQLR$TEST (char *data)
{
    printf ("data is [%s] \n", data);
    return SQLR$_NORMAL;
}
```

But when I execute my program on Pascal, I get the next output

```
data is []
```

What do I need to change for passing the argument to C-function from Pascal correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
%stdescr query_dsc : [CLASS_S] PACKED ARRAY [$L1..$U1: INTEGER] OF CHAR
```

and

```
query : PACKED ARRAY [1..40] OF CHAR VALUE 'select * from countries';
```